# Javascript or jQuery library to create photo slider

Tags: library, javascript, photography, jquery

a bit of a newbie question here. I would like to use a javascript or jquery library to create the following effect:

[image]

That is like a picture slider that changes on mouse over making the selected picture bigger. I have been looking for a library that would do this and cannot find it. I'm sure it's out there, but maybe I am not using the correct keywords to search for it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you,

D

Answer (score 0):

This is tagged as JS and JQ - so I'm assuming that you've got the skills needed to implement solutions that require you to work in code. One of the most customisable slider packages out there is Owl Carousel.

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Some tweaking to it will need to be done to get the effect you're going for. Should be possible with just some css changes to the middle image. Also, it looks like the image moving is on click, as opposed to on mouseover.

Assuming you don't have the skills to play in the code sandbox, I'd recommend you find a decent Wordpress Plugin. There are a lot of options, so pick your poison: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/image-slider/